# 'ReportServiceConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'ReportingEngineConfiguration' error in Telerik Web Report Designer (dotNetCore) api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, telerik-reporting

I have built a Telerik Web Report Designer web api using the dotNetCore and it has an issue of 'ReportServiceConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'ReportingEngineConfiguration' I have installed all dll libraries as well. It occurs in the program.cs file.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp => new ReportServiceConfiguration
        {
            ReportingEngineConfiguration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>(),
            HostAppId = "newcumstomreportAPI",
            Storage = new FileStorage(),
            ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(
                Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Reports"))
        });
```

What can be the issue for this? what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the full name of ReportServiceConfiguration?

I tried with the package in a .net 6 webapi project:

[image]

tried with

```
Telerik.Reporting.Services.ReportServiceConfiguration
```

[image]

no error occored:

[image]

Comment: yes, I have tried it. it works. But I'm using telerik signed dll files. not the Nuget package. That is the problem.

Comment: How you tried with dll files? are you trying follow this doc? https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/vs-integration/introduction#installing-in-visual-studio have  you checked if you were trying with dll  files for  .net framwork not for .net core